# bazel: how to create a rule that strips relative path of all files in subfolders

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to write a bazel BUILD for [GSL](https://github.com/ampl/gsl)

the problem is that it has various gsl_*.h header files in subfolders, but they are always included as `#include <gsl/gsl_somename.h>` so for example the header gsl_errno.h that lives in gsl/err/gsl_errno.h is included as `#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>` and `gsl_math.h` that lives in gsl/gsl_math.h is also included as `#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>`.

I tried to create a separate cc_library for each folder and use `strip_include_prefix` and `include_prefix` like so:

```
cc_library(
    name = "gsl_sys",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    srcs = [
        "sys/minmax.c",
        "sys/prec.c",
        "sys/hypot.c",
        "sys/log1p.c",
        "sys/expm1.c",
        "sys/coerce.c",
        "sys/invhyp.c",
        "sys/pow_int.c",
        "sys/infnan.c",
        "sys/fdiv.c",
        "sys/fcmp.c",
        "sys/ldfrexp.c",
    ],
    hdrs = glob(
        include = ["sys/*.h"],
    ),
    strip_include_prefix = "sys/",
    include_prefix = "gsl/",
)
```

but the problem is if I go by folder then there are circular dependencies (for example gsl/gsl_math.h includes gsl/sys/gsl_sys.h but some files in gsl/sys include gsl_*.h files that live in the gsl/ root folder.

I think optimally I'd have one cc_library with all the gsl_*.h files but such that they are all accessible as `#include <gsl/gsl_*.h>` independently of what subfolder they are in.

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I would copy them all to a new folder, and then use those new copied versions for your `cc_library`. A [genrule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html) is the simplest way to do this. Something like this in a BUILD file at the top level (don't put BUILD files in any of the subfolders; you want it all in the same package so one rule can handle all the files):

```py
# You could list all the headers instead of the glob, or something
# similar, if you only want a subset of them.
all_headers = glob(["gsl/*/*.h"])
# This is the logic for actually remapping the paths. Consider a macro
# instead of writing it inline like this if it gets more complicated.
unified_header_paths = ["unified_gsl/" + p.split("/")[-1] for p in all_headers]
genrule(
    name = "unified_gsl"
    srcs = all_headers,
    outs = unified_header_paths,
    cmd = "\n".join(["cp $(location %s) $(location %s)" %
        (src, dest) for src, dest in zip(all_headers, unified_header_paths)]),
)
```

The files would end up like this after copying:

```py
unified_gsl/gsl/gsl_math.h
unified_gsl/gsl/gsl_sys.h
```

And then you can write a cc_library like:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "gsl_headers",
    hdrs = [":unified_gsl"],
    strip_include_prefix = "unified_gsl/",
)
```

`cc_library.hdrs` is looking for files, so it will grab all the outputs from the `genrule`.

If you want to do more complicated things with the files than just moving them around, consider a full [custom rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html). If you include all the copied headers in your [`DefaultInfo.files`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/DefaultInfo.html#files), then just passing the target's label to `cc_library.hdrs` will work like it does with the genrule.